# Duplex binding possible with ONE incoming port in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Is duplex binding possible with having ONE single port open for incoming connections in WCF?

quoted from another question in SO...
"I am making a business specific messaging application, it is going to connect between 5000 and 10,000 machines back to our datacenter via WCF (no vpns, all over the net). It is mainly for alerts and I need to be able to send message direclty to specific clients"

That's the same way my application works.I can't make every user do port forwarding to open ports on their clients.
(But,I can open ports on the server)

So,Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,
and you could use Duplex WCF over HTTP on port 80 for doing so, as in this example

http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/09/scale-out-of-silverlight-http-polling.html